# Load XSL from another domain

Tags: xslt, cross-domain, cross-domain-policy

One and a half questions:

1)  Does [crossdomain.xml](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/AppSec/CrossDomain_PolicyFile_Specification.pdf) only work for Flash?

1a)  If so, is there a way to allow the loading of files across domains in the general case?  (E.g., serve an XML page with a cross-domain stylesheet declaration to a browser.)

Answer (score 2):

In newer browser CORS should work, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing. So basically the browser and the server need to cooperate, with the browser requesting the document and the server being configured to allow the access.

Comment: It looks like this requires Javascript?  The example I put for 1a is specifically what I'm trying to do - serve XML to a browser and have it load the XSL from a different domain.

Comment: In my understanding the mechanism does not rely on nor require Javascript. And http://home.versanet.de/~martin-honnen/xslt/test2013073004.xml works fine for me with Firefox, it requests a stylesheet on a different server (in a directory for which the server is configured to allow access from any origin by sending `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`). But unfortunately this does not seem to work with other browsers like Opera or Chrome or Opera although the Wikipedia page says they support CORS. It might be that CORS in those browsers is restricted to `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: As you say, it looks ilke it does work in Fireforx, but it doesn't work in Chrome (nor IE 9, which is explicitly listed as supported only through XDomainRequest).

Comment: An xsl file with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` wildcard will still be blocked in Chrome. Must be needing a specific origin domain set?